# C++ Compiling Issues

Tags: c++

When compiled using g++ MainStudent.cpp Student.cpp

These are the errors i get :

> MainStudent.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: MainStudent.cpp:23:38:
>   error: no matching function for call to ‘Student::Student(char [10],
>   char [10], int&, double [3])’ MainStudent.cpp:23:38: note: candidates
>   are: Student.h:13:2: note: Student::Student(char*, char*, int, double)
>   Student.h:13:2: note:   no known conversion for argument 4 from
>   ‘double [3]’ to ‘double’ Student.h:5:7: note: Student::Student(const
>   Student&) Student.h:5:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 4
>   provided Student.cpp: In constructor ‘Student::Student(char*, char*,
>   int, double)’: Student.cpp:9:11: error: incompatible types in
>   assignment of ‘double’ to ‘double [3]’ Student.cpp: At global scope:
>   Student.cpp:14:5: error: prototype for ‘int Student::Getage()’ does
>   not match any in class ‘Student’ Student.h:16:7: error: candidate is:
>   int* Student::Getage() Student.cpp:15:8: error: prototype for ‘double
>   Student::Getmarks()’ does not match any in class ‘Student’
>   Student.h:17:10: error: candidate is: double* Student::Getmarks()

I can't figure out where the problem lies...

Comment: Why? Did you read the errors/ Which one you don't understand?

Comment: I don't understand the first one that says it can't finding the matching function which is the constructor.

Comment: `no known conversion for argument 4 from ‘double [3]’ to ‘double’ `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor is

```
Student::Student (char *fname, char *lname, int age, double marks)
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But you are trying to pass an array to it in

```
double marks[3];
//...
Student st1(fname, lname, age, marks);
```

You either need to get rid of the array in the class and just take a double or change the constructor to take a double array and then copy it in the constructor like

```
Student::Student (char *fname, char *lname, int age, const double (&marks)[3]) {
//                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use array of size 3 
//                                                   since that is what _marks is
    strcpy(_fname, fname);
    strcpy(_lname, lname);
    _age = age;

    for (int i =  0; i < 3; i++)
    _marks[i] = marks[i];
}
```

Comment: How can I change the constructor to accept double array?

Comment: @acer I just added that.

Comment: Thank you sir, it helped solve all the other errors as well.

Comment: You should probably restrict the array to length 3, no?

Comment: @juanchopanza I changed the signature but I was under the belief that it still decays to a `double *`

Comment: I mean you can pass a (`const`) reference to an array

Comment: @juanchopanza Ah.  Good suggestion.  I added it into the code.